# using inno setup how to update application with version?

Tags: windows, inno-setup, auto-update

I'm using Inno Setup to create an installer,I want the installer to update with new version of application.
how can we update application using inno setup , anyone can help?

Comment: You do not have to create an "update application". Just rebuild your installer with the new version of the application.

Comment: To add to Martin's comments: In Inno Setup terminology, an "update" or "upgrade" means "install new version to same directory as previous version, updating files as necessary."

Comment: It seems that you have posted a new and more meaningful question under a different account: [How to update python desktop application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66491911/850848)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reuse the former insteller, set a new version number and let the application id unchanged.
Inno Setup then automatically updates a installed version of your application or installs new if it not exists.

Comment: From the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66491911/850848) (probably by the same user), it does not look like it's what OP looks for.